# If f:[0,∞)→R is a **continuous and bounded** function -> so f has a maximum, minimum or both

Tags: functions

I need to find an example that contradicts this next sentence:

If f:[0,∞)→R is a **continuous and bounded** function -> so f has a maximum, minimum or both

Any tips about how to solve this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(x)\cdot\arctan(x)$

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer!